# Variable types in Java?

Tags: java, variables, object, parameters

Sometimes I see methods that have a parameter like `public method(ObjectName variable)`

Does that mean this method only accepts `ClassName`'s objects? For example from another class?

it might be a simple question but I am used to seeing only `int's`, `String`s etc. as parameters. I guess some methods can accept instances of other classes? How does compiler know then that the class in the parameter is valid? Does it know it from imports?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes to all your questions. Some methods accept instances of classes, both others or this class. Compiler knows by imports and the other classes in the package. If you have a more specific question put some code up.

Answer (score 0):

The formal rules can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Basically if a method accepts class `A` then it can also accept any subclass of `A`. A can be any class, `BigInteger` `InputStream` `URL` etc. If a method can accepts interface `B` then it will also accept any class that implements `B`.